# Can't adjust bootstrap table row height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I would like to adjust the height of the table rows to 24px.  I've tried putting the row height in the top CSS as well as writing it inline.

CSS:

```
tbody tr {
    line-height: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0;
}

tbody td {
    line-height: 24px; 
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>

    <thead id='dontMove'>

        <tr id='theRow'>

            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Applicants</th>
            <th># Enrolled</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody style='font-size: 12px;'>

        <tr style='height: 24px;'>

            <td style='height: 20px;'>Contents</td>

        </tr>

        <!-- rest of table contents -->

    </tbody>

</table>
```

However, nothing seems to be making the table rows adjust the height. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -2):

Wrap your table content in a div like this with a cellpadding of 24

```
<table cellpadding="24">
    <thead id='dontMove'> 
        <tr id='theRow'>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Applicants</th>
            <th># Enrolled</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style='font-size: 12px;'> 
        <tr style='height: 24px;'>
            <td style='height: 20px;'>Contents</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See this example for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp